# Does underscore.js creates anonym func objects in _.each that needs to be garbaged?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, underscore.js, anonymous-function

I use a lot _.each instead of the for loop in my code. Does _.each function from the Underscore.js library create a new anonymous function on each call? Eg.

```
_.each(this.sprites, function(sprite) {
    sprite.draw();
    this.spriteDraws++
}, this);
```

Does the Unerscore.js create a new anonymous function on each frame of the application loop? Does this function needs to be garbage collected?

I have noticed that my application creates a buch of new objects each frame and am not able to root them out (a nonascending sawtooth pattern - on each frame, the same number of objects gets created and afterwards garbaged periodically). Maybe this could be a reason.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
As stupid as it may seem, I've realized that I am the culprit. In every call to _.each, I am creating a new anonymous function and passing it to the Underscore.js. Thank you Bergi on confirming it. I've tested the code and it already creates less objects.

*An updated question*: 
Should one rather predifine a function and put it in a variable for the reuse? Or should one rather use a more traditional for loop when dealing witha arrays?

Comment: I haven't read into the documentation, but my guess is that `_` has a method called each, which passes the each function on to `Array.prototype.forEach`. If this is so, no new object is created.

Comment: *You* are creating an object with your function expression.

Comment: Yeah! You are right Bergi, I've just realized it few hours ago when I asked this question :) Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't

From: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js

```
  // The cornerstone, an `each` implementation, aka `forEach`.
  // Handles raw objects in addition to array-likes. Treats all
  // sparse array-likes as if they were dense.
  _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context);
    var i, length;
    if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
      for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
      }
    } else {
      var keys = _.keys(obj);
      for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
        iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

Comment: You will want to look into `optimizeCb`, though.